# C++ pointer to member function getting an error : not a function or function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

Here is what I have:

A class PostfixCalculator, with public member methods:

```
class PostfixCalculator
{

public:
    PostfixCalculator();

    int  top();
    int  popTop();
    void pushNum(int);
    void add();
    void minus();
    void multiply();
    void divide();
    void negate();
    bool empty();
    void pushSymbol(string);
```

and when I try to call a member function by pointer to member function, I tried something like the following (I know the method does not make much sense, it is just a test):

```
void PostfixCalculator::pushSymbol(string str)
{
    func f = &PostfixCalculator::add;
    this.*(f)();
}
```

However, I get the following compiler error:

```
> postfixCalculator.cpp:84:12: error: called object type 'func' (aka
> 'void (PostfixCalculator::*)()') is not a function or function pointer
>                 this.*(f)();
>                       ~~~^ 1 error generated.
```

I am using clang++ to compile my program, under fedora linux.

Comment: what's `func` that you use?

Comment: Off topic: Take a look at [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). They automate and hide most of the nastiness from sight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `this` is a pointer, meaning you have to apply `->*` to it, but not `.*`. If you want to use `.*`, you have to dereference `this` with `*` first.

Secondly, function call operator `()` has higher priority than `.*` or `->*` operators, meaning that you need extra parentheses to make sure that the pointer `f` is dereferenced first, and the function call `()` is applied to the result of that dereference.

Should be

```
(this->*f)();
```

or alternatively

```
(*this.*f)();
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a pointer so you should use `->` and deref * have lower priority than function call `()`, so you should use `(this->*f)()`